# Mostrar arquivo no solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio

Quando é aberto um arquivo no visual studio, ele fica pendurado na parte de cima, ai sempre no final do dia tem um monte de coisa pendurada e eu queria saber como faz para que quando eu clique em um desses arquivos seja mostrado no solution explorer em qual pasta esta o arquivo que foi clicado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions

Marque o item "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Ronaldo

Comment: Se tiver funcionado, vote positivo na resposta e/ou marque ela como correta. Isso facilita pros futuros usuários que estiverem passando pela mesma situação.

Answer (score -3):

Interessante que não tem a opção semelhante ao VS Code de exibir na side bar.
Não que essa solução seja 'ruim' mas fica mudando a cada arquivo aberto, seria interessante ter a opção somente quando necessário de exibir no Solution Explorer, tal qual o VS Code faz